# Generating number within range with equal probability with dice

Tags: algorithm, probability, puzzle, discrete-mathematics

I've been thinking about this but can't seem to figure it out. I need to pick a random integer between 1 to 50 (inclusive) in such a way that each of the integer in it would be equally likely. I will have to do this using a 8 sided dice and a 15 sided dice.

I've read somewhat similar questions related to random number generators with dices but I am still confused. I think it is somewhere along the line of partitioning the numbers into sets. Then, I would roll a die, and then, depending on the outcome, decide which die to roll again.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try till now? SO is not a code/algorithm writing service, I'm sorry.

Comment: Some ideas here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-a-fair-6-sided-die-to-generate-a-random-number-from-1-to-20-with-each-outcome-occurring-with-the-same-probability

Answer (score 1):

As a simple - not necessarily "optimal" solution, roll the 8 sided die, then the 15 sided:

```
8 sided   15 sided   1..50 result
1 or 2    1..15      1..15
3 or 4    1..15      16..30 (add 15 to 15-sided roll)
5 or 6    1..15      31..45 (add 30 to 15-sided roll)
7 or 8    1..5       46..50 (add 45 to 15-sided roll)
7 or 8    6..15      start again / reroll both dice
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have two functions: `d8()`, which returns a number from 0 to 7, and `d15()`, which returns a number from 0 to 14.  You want to write a `d50()` that returns a number from 0 to 49.

Of all the simple ways, this one is probably the most efficient in terms of how many dice you have to roll, and something like this will work for all combinations of dice you have and dice you want:

```
int d50()
{
   int result;
   do
   {
       result = d8()*8+d8(); //random from 0 to 63
   } while(result >=50);
   return result;
}
```

If you want really constant time, you can do this:

```
int d50()
{
   int result = d15();
   int result = result*15+d15();  //0 to 225
   int result = result*8+d8(); //0 to 1799
   return result/36; //integer division rounds down
}
```

This way combines dice until the number of possibilities (1800) is evenly divisible by 50, so the same number of possibilities correspond to each result.  This works OK in this case, but doesn't work if the prime factors of the dice you have (2, 3, and 5 in this case), don't cover the factors of the dice you want (2, 5)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can consider each dice result as a subdivision of a bigger interval. So throwing one 8 sided dice you choose one out the 8 major interval that divide your range of value. Throwing a 15 sided dice means selecting one out the 15 sub-interval and so on.
Considering that 15 = 3*5, 8 = 2*2*2 and 50 = 2*5*5 you can choose 36 = 3*3*2*2 as an handy multiple of 50 so that:

15*15*8 = 50*36 = 1800

You can even think of expressing the numbers from 0 to 1799 in base 15 and choose ramdomly the three digits:

choice = [0-7]*15^2 + [0-14]*15^1 + [0-14]*15^0

So my proposal, with a test of the distribution, is (in the c++ language):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> hist;
    int result;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());    // initialiaze the random generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> d8(0, 7);     // istantiate the dices
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> d15(0, 14);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {      // make a lot of throws...
        result = d8(gen) * 225;
        result += d15(gen) * 15;           // add to result
        result += d15(gen);
        ++hist[ result / 36 + 1];          // count each result 
    }
    for (auto p : hist) {                  // show the occurences of each result
       std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be something like this:

```
1 : 387
2 : 360
3 : 377
4 : 393
5 : 402
...
48 : 379
49 : 378
50 : 420
```